# Evaluation of Residua

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, residue-calculus

Suppose that I have the following complex valued function, and want to evaluate its residua:

$$h(z)=\frac {z^5}{(z-3)(z^4+2)}$$

For both parts of the denominator we will have simple poles. For our first pole we will have,

$$z_1-3 \Rightarrow z_1=3$$

And for the second part of the denominator we will have three different poles for $k=0,1,2,3$, of the form,

$$z_{0,1,2,3}=2^{\frac14}e^{\frac {i\pi(2k+1)}4}$$

Now, when actually evaluating the residua, should I evaluate the residue at $z_{0,1,2,3}$ seperately for each $z_0,z_1,z_2$, and $z_3$, or should I evaluate it just as the general expression given above?

In the solutions to my notes they done the latter, but I am not sure why. Would anybody be able to explain why you would evaluate it as one, when they are distinct poles?

$\mathbf {Edit:}$

One such example that I refer to, straight out of my notes, is the following:

$$Res_{z=(2n+1)\frac \pi2i}f(z)=\lim_{z=(2n+1)\frac \pi2i}\frac{(z-(2n+1)\frac\pi2i)}
{\cosh(z)}$$

$$=\lim_{z=(2n+1)\frac \pi2i}(\frac{1}{\sinh(z)})$$

$$=\frac1{i\sin(2n+1)\frac\pi2}\tag{By L'Hopital}$$

$$=-i(-1)^n$$

$$=(-1)^{n+1}i$$

I understand that it might not be of exactly the same form, but it does include, still, the periodicity of the solution for different $k$.

Comment: For the second part of the denominator you actually have four poles. You have to include $k=0$.

Comment: Yeah that's right, thanks for pointing that out, I'll Change it now.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You have to specify at which point you are calculating the residue of the function, so, separately.

Comment: It's just that in my notes when we had poles of the above form or similar, whereby we had simple poles determined by different values of k, periodic in nature, the residues were calculated in a "General form", without needing to consider each pole for a different k, and then to find each of their residues.

Comment: Can you add that general expression to your question?

Comment: @Rol, just added now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If $f(z)$ has only simple poles, then
$$
\operatorname*{Res}_{z=a}f(z)=\lim_{z\to a}(z-a)f(z)
$$
For example, if $a$ is any of the roots $z^4+2$, we can use L'Hôpital:
$$
\begin{align}
\operatorname*{Res}_{z=a}f(z)
&=\lim_{z\to a}\frac{z-a}{(z-3)(z^4+2)}\\
&=\lim_{z\to a}\frac{1}{\color{#C00000}{(z^4+2)}+\color{#00A000}{(z-3)4z^3}}\\
&=\frac1{\color{#C00000}{0}+\color{#00A000}{4a^4-12a^3}}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I think I see, thank you very much!

Comment: I seen that if I do this as you suggested I actually get zero for this residue, is that correct? In my calculation I included z^3 in the numerator

Comment: What residue are you computing?

Comment: That of the original question, at the very start, for the second part of the denominator. It's as you done except you appear to have missed out the numerator z^5 in your working.

Comment: Yes, but what at which singularity are you computing the residue (there are $5$ singularities)?